# Standard Deviation of $26$ cards without replacement

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation

I am trying to find the Standard Deviation of $26$ cards from a normal deck of $52$ cards without replacement.

I understand that to calculate it with replacement, we get variance of $1$ card as $14$ and variance of $26$ cards as $26\cdot14 = 364$ which gives the standard deviation of the $26$ cards as $\sqrt{364}$ which is $19.07$.

How do we calculate this for without replacement now?

Comment: How are you defining the value of a card?

Comment: Standard cards valued from 1-13

Comment: Then I will share my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4783991/82793) from a similar question, which should still be general enough to apply.